# Setting a item in a forms property from another forms vba

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a form which has a button that has a click procedure.
Essentially, if a `checkbox(chkIncludeIDs)` is ticked then it has to open a form and make the property of a textbox on that form visible.

My current code for the click event is as follows:

```
Private Sub Update_pending_Click()
On Error GoTo Err_Update_pending_Click

    Dim stDocName As String
    Dim stLinkCriteria As String
    
    If Me.chkIncludeIDs = 0 Then
        stDocName = "Pending Queries Locked"
    Else
        stDocName = "Pending Queries Locked"
        Forms![Pending Queries Locked]!ID.Visible = True
    End If
    DoCmd.OpenForm stDocName, , , stLinkCriteria

Exit_Update_pending_Click:
    Exit Sub

Err_Update_pending_Click:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume Exit_Update_pending_Click
    
End Sub
```

The form that I open is "Pending Queries Locked"
The textbox I need making visible is ID as it's default value is `visible = false`.

My code isn't working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please name your controls without spaces like "form_pending_queries_locked", query_my_query, txt_id, lbl_id for many good reasons.

when you access a control's property you need to specify which property you are accessing.
e.g

```
If Me.chkIncludeIDs.value <> 0 Then
```

regarding your question. You need to open the form first before accessing its controls. so that would be logically: open the form, access the control, change its property.

in code it would be

```
Dim txt_id As Textbox
DoCmd.OpenForm "frm_myform"
Set txt_id = Forms![frm_myform]!txt_id

txt_id.visible = False
```

or alternatively: you can send a parameter via OpenArg and access it via on form_load event which will then change local controls properties..